# Accessing Nested Attributes in a WordPress Gutenberg block via PHP

Tags: nested, attributes, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a working WordPress Gutenberg Block project which uses nested blocks. I'm trying to rewrite the javascript save function in PHP to create a dynamic block.

I've modified the PHP file to include the following:

```
function render_html($attributes) {
    
    var_dump($attributes);

    ob_start(); ?>
      <h1>Attributes</h1>
      <h3>The number of columns is <?php echo esc_html($attributes['myColumns']) ?>!</h3>
      <?php return ob_get_clean();

}
function cards_init() {
   register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__, array(
       'render_callback' => 'render_html'
   ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cards_init' );
```

This displays the top level attributes correctly (just one value):

```
C:\Users\Steve\Local Sites\netmonics6\app\public\wp-content\plugins\cards\cards.php:32:
array (size=1)
  'myColumns' => int 3

Attributes
The number of columns is 3!
```

I'm just wondering how I access the attributes for the nested blocks?

I've used Innerblocks in the main edit.js as follows to enable a nested block:

```
<InnerBlocks
    allowedBlocks={['some-name/card']}
    orientation="horizontal"
    template={[
        ['some-name/card'],
        ['some-name/card'],
        ['some-name/card'],
    ]}
/>
```

Does anyone please have any ideas?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

InnerBlocks can be accessed via `$block` in the `render_callback` function. The [syntax for the render callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/#php) is `function($attributes, $content, $block)` although commonly, only `$attributes` is used - unless you want to access something `<InnerBlocks>`, eg:

**PHP**

```php
/*
* Render callback function
* @return string HTML markup
*/
function render_html($attributes, $content, $block)
{
    $output = '';

    // Loop through each inner block
    foreach ($block->inner_blocks as $inner_block) {
        // Eg. If your ['some-name/card'] block had an attribute 
        // called `someAttribute` (boolean), it could be accessed via:
        if ($inner_block->someAttribute == true) {
            // Do something different with this block
            $output .= sprintf('<div class="is-some-attribute">%s</div>', $inner_block->render());
        } else {
            // Otherwise, render block as usual..
            $output .= $inner_block->render();
        }
    }
    /* 
     * Tip: Always return the content to render
     * echo() should not be used in render_callback() and ob_start/ob_get_clean not needed.
     * Returning valid content avoids dreaded "Invalid JSON" error in Editor.
     */
    return $output;
}
```

When using InnerBlocks, the save() function in JavaScript is required so that the block editor saves the InnerBlock content (even if you are using a PHP `render_callback`), eg:

**save.js**

```js
export default function save() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Depending on what you need from the InnerBlocks, [block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) might also be useful too..

Comment: Hello S.Walsh, Thank you so much for your reply and code example. I have tried it out, it's fantastic. One thing I've noticed is that some things repeat, so for example attributes are shown in 3 places, under parsed_block, block_type and also appears under attributes at the top level. I assume I should use the top level and ignore the others. Also the context attributes (if that's the correct name?) are available twice, in available_context and in context. Not sure if it makes any difference which I use. Steve

Comment: Just wondering how I could run some javascript after the block loads.

In the php file, I've tried including a .js file as follows:
require_once('plugin.js');
Then write some javascript into the $output variable:

$output .= '<script language="javascript">';
$output .= 'SomeFunction();';
$output .= '</script>';

This does work, I doubt it's correct to include a js file in this way.

There is also a problem when I have two instances of the block on the same page. The SomeFunction() function only runs once.

Is there a better way to include a javascript file and make a call?